# Can't get FreeType to render

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype

Working with OpenGL, GLM, GLAD, GLFW and FreeType attempting to get fonts to render. I've stepped through to make sure no OpenGL errors had occured while rendering, nothing posts an error code, but nothing renders to the screen. I'm also not sure if I'm using glm's ortho function correctly, because i'm not sure where to actually use the variable:

```
glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, 800.0f, 0.0f, 600.0f);
```

This is my Draw Loop, it gets called after the scene Initializes:

```
void GameLoop::Run()
{
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(m_game_window))
    {
        // Do That thing where you draw everything
    }
}
```

The Font constructor which loads the font into textures:

```
Salem::Graphics::Font::Font(std::string p_font_path)
{
    FT_Library ft;
    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft))
    {
        std::cout << "Error loading FreeType library" << std::endl;
    }

    FT_Face face;
    if (FT_New_Face(ft, p_font_path.c_str(), 0, &face))
    {
        std::cout << "Error loading font;\n" << p_font_path << std::endl;
    }

    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 28);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); // Disable byte-alignment restriction

    for (GLubyte c = 0; c < 128; c++)
    {
        if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to load a character glyph." << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        GLuint texture;
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glTexImage2D(
                GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                0,
                GL_RED,
                face->glyph->bitmap.width,
                face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
                0,
                GL_RED,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                face->glyph->bitmap.buffer);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        Character character = {
                texture,
                glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows),
                glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top),
                face->glyph->advance.x
        };

        m_characters.insert(std::make_pair(c, character));
    }

    FT_Done_Face(face);
    FT_Done_FreeType(ft);
    std::cout << "Font loaded. " << std::endl;
}
```

My text's Initialize function:

```
void Text::Initialize()
{
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, 800.0f, 0.0f, 600.0f);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_vbo);

    glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6 * 4, nullptr, m_draw_method);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), nullptr);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

And my text's draw function:

```
void Text::Draw()
{
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, 800.0f, 0.0f, 600.0f);

    shader()->Use();
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader()->id(), "textColor"), m_color.x, m_color.y, m_color.z);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindVertexArray(m_vao);

    for (std::string::const_iterator c = m_text.begin(); c != m_text.end(); ++c)
    {
        Character ch = m_font.characters()[*c];

        GLfloat xPosition = m_position.x + ch.Bearing.x * m_scale;
        GLfloat yPosition = m_position.y - (ch.Size.y - ch.Bearing.y) * m_scale;

        GLfloat width = ch.Size.x * m_scale;
        GLfloat height = ch.Size.y * m_scale;

        GLfloat vertices[6][4] = {
                {xPosition,         yPosition + height, 0.0, 0.0},
                {xPosition,         yPosition,          0.0, 1.0},
                {xPosition + width, yPosition,          1.0, 1.0},

                {xPosition,         yPosition + height, 0.0, 0.0},
                {xPosition + width, yPosition,          1.0, 1.0},
                {xPosition + width, yPosition + height, 1.0, 0.0}
        };

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.TextureID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
        //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        m_position.x += (ch.Advance >> 6) * m_scale;
    }

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Didn't want the post to be too long, if my shaders are needed, let me know.

Comment: This is _way_ too long. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: How's that? Sorry, there seems to be a few places this could be failing wasn't really sure what all i should include. Debugging openGL can be a pain.

Comment: Read the linked article. Then, if you are still lost, try this: write something that renders one object without shaders and textures at the most convenient location once, post it if it fails, extend it if it doesn't.

Comment: @PasserBy: Rendering without shaders isn't possible in core OpenGL.

Comment: @NicolBolas Tells you how much I know about OpenGL ;) Although, to be fair, libraries based on OpenGL did a good job of making that fact not obvious.

Comment: @PasserBy You can render without shaders in OpenGL just not with the core profile.

Answer (score 1):

Upon breaking up the code, i found a helpful resource which lead me to my problem. From https://learnopengl.com/#!In-Practice/Text-Rendering Project source, I found that my orthographic projection variable had to be passed to my shader program when I was Constructing the font. I did this by add the following code to my Font Constructor:

```
glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, 800.0f, 0.0f, 600.0f);
p_shader->Use();
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(p_shader->id(), "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
```